# How to apply custom validation for two fields in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I need to apply custom validation for two fields, but failing. It is applying only to one field.

I created file select_option_validator.rb in lib folder, and here is code:

```
class SelectOptionValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator  
 def validate_each(object, attribute, value)  
   if value == "--- please select ---"  
    object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "should be selected")  
   end  
  end  
end
```

Here is my validations in model:

```
   validates :category, :select_option => true

   validates :language, :select_option => true
```

My view:

```
  <% if @website.errors.any? %>
   <div class="alert alert-error">
     <%= pluralize(@website.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
    this website from being saved:
   </div>
   <div class="error_explanation">
   <ul>
    <% @website.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

but it gives me only

```
    * Language should be selected
```

but should be also

```
    * Category should be selected.
```

Why category isn't validating ?

Comment: What's the value of "category"?

Comment: @Dave, the same as language. I mean not valid value.

Comment: Looks perfectly valid for me. My bet: `value != "--- please select ---"` so you probably should check why. Use [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) to get `value`.